# Mapping booleans to date ranges in a relational database

Tags: relational-database, range

I'm not quite sure wether my title is worded right.

Say you have a database for a car rental service that contains information on what car will be rented out at what time(s). The cars can be rented out multiple days at a time, but never less than one day (so the time is atomic).

How would you fit that in to a relational database? Do you have a row for each date with a boolean representing wether the car will be in use that day? Or do you work it in some other way?

Extra question: What solution would make checking how many cars are rented out at a specific time the easiest/fastest?

thanks,

robin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the car rental table have a car rental checkout date and a car rental checkin date and you can tell if a car will be rented out on a given day by
`WHERE $date_to_check BETWEEN checkout_date AND checkin_date`

Answer (score 0):

Why not make two tables: CARS and RENTALS?

In CARS you keep all the information about the physical car (model, date made, etc..).
In RENTALS you keep all the information about the rental itself (starting time rental, end time rental, etc...)

You relate them with a foreign key in RENTALS that points to the ID car.

```
        CARS                                        RENTALS
idCar | model | ....            idRental | xIdCar | startDate        |     endDate
  1     Honda                       1         1     1/1/2010 10:30     1/1/2010 18:30
                                    2         1     1/1/2010 19:00     2/1/2010 10:30
```

That should solve both your questions, since you only need to query the rentals for the dates you need and join with the cars